# until loop for bash scripting

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting, infinite-loop

I want to use Until loop command in the following way, Using until loop so that script should not end if condition is false

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p " enter the App name : " app
file="/logs/$app/$app.log"
if ! [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "$app.log not found, Please check correct log name in deployer"
    exit
fi

format=$(head -1 $file | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')
format1=$(tail -1 $file | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')
read -p " Enter the Date in this Format --'$format' : " first
until grep -q "$first" "$file"
do
  echo "Date not found"
  read -p " Enter the Date in this Format --'$format' : " first
done
final_first=$first
echo "logs are present till this '$format1' date, use this date if you want logs from Provided to latest."
read -p "Enter the end date : " end
until grep -q "$end" "$file"
do
  echo "Date not found"
  read -p "Enter the end date : " end
done
final_end=$end
cd /logs/$app
sed -n " /$final_first/,/$final_end/ "p $file >$app.txt
zip $app.zip $app.txt
rm $app.txt
```

but I am getting this input

```
$ ./test
 enter the App name : cspt
 Enter the Date in this Format --'Sep 08 04:53:30' : er
logs are present till this 'at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) ' date, use this date if you want logs from Provided to latest.
Enter the end date : Sep 08 04:53:30
  adding: cspt.txt (deflated 99%)
```

Here it not taking end date.. and generating log file

Comment: Spaces matter. You need spaces around `[` and `]` in tests. That being said you don't want `[ ... ]` here at all. You want the exit status of `grep` so you just want `until grep ...; do`.

Comment: @EtanReisner the script failed again now it not going to next step $ ./test
 enter the App name : cspt
 Enter the Date in this Format --'Sep 08 04:53:30' : er
logs are present till this 'at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) ' date, use this date if you want logs from Provided to latest.
Enter the end date : Sep 08 04:53:30
  adding: cspt.txt (deflated 99%)
here he didn't asked end date now

Comment: If you still have a problem you can edit the post with the updated script and the updated error to "replace" the question with the new one (since the original one was, essentially, a typo). (This isn't generally useful practice on SO however.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Please help me in above query

Comment: @John Bollinger Please help me in above query

Comment: I rolled back your most recent edit because you had an answer to the question that was being asked before you made that change and the change invalidated the answer. (I'm not sure the previous question was very clear though but it was attempted to be answered.) If you have an additional question you can add it as a "bonus" question or (better) mark this as answered if it is and ask a *new* question for help with the added feature.

Answer (score 1):

> but I am getting this input

```
$ ./test
 enter the App name : cspt
 Enter the Date in this Format --'Sep 08 04:53:30' : er
logs are present till this 'at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) ' date, use this date if you want logs from Provided to latest.
Enter the end date : Sep 08 04:53:30
  adding: cspt.txt (deflated 99%)
```

> Here it not taking end date.. and generating log file

On the contrary, it looks like it indeed is prompting for and reading an end date (given as `Sep 08 04:53:30` in the example).  Do you perhaps mean to say that you expect the script to reject `er` as a start date?

Perhaps the script could be made more discriminating, but I see no reason to think it's doing anything different from what you told it to do.  You accept as a start "date" any string that appears anywhere in the file, more or less.  It is not unreasonable to think that the string "er" would appear somewhere in a lengthy log file.

Note also, however, that your script may behave unexpectedly if either of the given "dates" contains regex metacharacters.  Such dates may be matched where you don't expect.

Furthermore, dates containing slash (`/`) characters will cause problems for your `sed` command.